# Как подставить переменные при запросе MySql node.js (Синтаксис)

Tags: node.js

Как подставить переменные при запросе?

```
connection.query("UPDATE `raund_table` SET `round`=1,`activ`=1,`time_in`=1,`time_out`=2,`action_room`=1 WHERE `room`=1000",
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(results);
        });
    connection.end();
})
```

Пытаюсь так через пагинацию. Но не чего не получается:

```
connection.query("UPDATE `raund_table` SET `round`="+val.raund+",`activ`="+val.act+",`time_in`="+timeUNIX()+",`time_out`=2,`action_room`=1 WHERE `room`=1000",
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(results);
        });
    connection.end();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напрямую подставлять данные нельзя, это может вызывать [sql injection](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

В документации ([node-mysql](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql), [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)) есть пример, который показывает как подставлять параметры. В вашем случае это будет выглядить так:

```
// отдельная переменная для читабельность
const sql = "UPDATE `raund_table` SET `round`= ?, `activ`= ?, `time_in`= ?, `time_out`=2, `action_room`=1 WHERE `room`=1000"; 
const params = [val.raund, val.act, timeUNIX()];
connection.query(sql, params,
        function(err, results) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            resolve(results);
        });
    connection.end();
})
```

Так же я обратил внимания, что вы используете промисы, но оборачиваете функцию самостоятельно. Если использовать [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2), то это делается значительно проще и красивее:

```
const sql = "UPDATE `raund_table` SET `round`= ?, `activ`= ?, `time_in`= ?, `time_out`=2, `action_room`=1 WHERE `room`=1000"; 
const params = [val.raund, val.act, timeUNIX()];
const [rows,fields] = await connection.query(sql, params);
```